# Django-filer: Set the default number of file upload widgets that appear on an admin model?

Tags: django-filer

I am trying to implement django-filer file upload into my admin model. It seems to be working fine except for the fact that I can see too many multiple file upload widgets when I create a new record in model admin. Each time I upload a new file, it adds another widget, so I always have several extra ones. Is there a way to limit the number of upload widgets that show up by default, so the user can just see, say, 1 extra widget, and then click "Add another file" when they want to add another file? Here is a screenshot of what I am currently seeing. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add "extra" in admin class:

```
class SomeImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = YourModel
    extra = 1
```